# Add geom_point on top of corresponding geom_boxplot representation

Tags: r, ggplot2

New in data representation and using ggplot2

I plotted data using boxplot like this

`p <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y, colour=foo, fill=bar)) 
p + geom_boxplot()`

> data my data_frame
>   x is a 3 level factor
>   y is numeric (obviously)
>   foo is a 2 level factor
>   bar is a 3 level factor

So I have  3 * 2 * 3 = **18 boxplots** (18 levels) from **3 different factors**

On **data** I have an other column with mostly NA and sometime the duplicated y value, let's call it **y_special** (Before I had just TRUE marker instead of a duplicated value in this column, but I later assumed it will be easier to plot it that way)

I would like to plot **y_special** with geom_point on top of the corresponding boxplot

Comment: Either `+ geom_point(aes(y = y_sepecial))` will work or you'll need to make [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Comment: I already tried this solution, it plots it on top of the factor x, but it does not dispatch on the other. So it plot the y_special at 3 different levels instead of 18. It is late, I will check tomorrow for reproductible exemple. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, like my comment said **or you'll need to make a reproducible example**. Please click the link in my first comment for tips on making a reproducible example. You can edit your question to include simulated data, built-in data, or if those don't work for you, real data shared with `dput()`.

Comment: Thanks :)! I will do

Comment: As part of that reproducible example, you will want to provide data.  You can use `dput` as in `dput(data)`.